Azure DevOps Pipeline : Environment 'demo' does not exist, would you like to create it?
I am trying to deploy Azure WebApp code using azd deploy For this I am setting following ENV for the pipeline

AZURE_ENV_NAME
AZURE_LOCATION
AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
AZURE_TENANT_ID
AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP

These are my pipeline steps :
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Install azd
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Install the Azure Developer CLI (azd)
        curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-azd.sh | bash
        # Run azd commands
        azd version

  - pwsh: |
      azd config set auth.useAzCliAuth "true"
    displayName: Configure AZD to Use AZ CLI Authentication.

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Deploy Application
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: Azure-Service-Connection-For-Pipeline
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        # azd deploy --no-prompt
        azd deploy
    env:
      AZURE_ENV_NAME: $(AZURE_ENV_NAME)
      AZURE_LOCATION: $(AZURE_LOCATION)
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: $(AZURE_TENANT_ID)
      AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: $(AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP)

But when pipeline runs, pipeline stuck at Environment 'demo' does not exist, would you like to create it? (y/N)
I have demo under DevOps Pipeline Environments.
Also have following azure.yaml
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-dev/main/schemas/v1.0/azure.yaml.json

name: azure-search-openai-demo
metadata:
  template: azure-search-openai-demo@0.0.2-beta
services:
  backend:
    project: ./app/backend
    language: py
    host: appservice
    hooks:
      prepackage:
        windows:
          shell: pwsh
          run:  cd ../frontend;npm install;npm run build
          interactive: false
          continueOnError: false
        posix:
          shell: sh
          run:  cd ../frontend;npm install;npm run build
          interactive: false
          continueOnError: false
pipeline:
  variables:
      - AZURE_OPENAI_SERVICE
      - AZURE_OPENAI_RESOURCE_GROUP
      - AZURE_FORMRECOGNIZER_SERVICE
      - AZURE_FORMRECOGNIZER_RESOURCE_GROUP
      - AZURE_FORMRECOGNIZER_SKU
      - AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX
      - AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE
      - AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE_RESOURCE_GROUP
      - AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE_LOCATION
      - AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE_SKU
      - AZURE_SEARCH_QUERY_LANGUAGE
      - AZURE_SEARCH_QUERY_SPELLER
      - AZURE_SEARCH_SEMANTIC_RANKER
      - AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT
      - AZURE_STORAGE_RESOURCE_GROUP
      - AZURE_STORAGE_SKU
      - AZURE_APP_SERVICE_SKU
      - AZURE_OPENAI_CHATGPT_DEPLOYMENT
      - AZURE_OPENAI_EMB_DEPLOYMENT
      - OPENAI_HOST
      - OPENAI_API_KEY
      - OPENAI_ORGANIZATION
      - AZURE_USE_APPLICATION_INSIGHTS
      - USE_VECTORS
      - USE_GPT4V
      - AZURE_VISION_ENDPOINT
      - VISION_SECRET_NAME
      - AZURE_KEY_VAULT_NAME
      - AZURE_USE_AUTHENTICATION
      - AZURE_ENFORCE_ACCESS_CONTROL
      - AZURE_AUTH_TENANT_ID
      - AZURE_SERVER_APP_ID
      - AZURE_CLIENT_APP_ID
      - ALLOWED_ORIGIN
  secrets:
      - AZURE_SERVER_APP_SECRET
      - AZURE_CLIENT_APP_SECRET
hooks:
    preprovision:
      windows:
        shell: pwsh
        run: ./scripts/auth_init.ps1
        interactive: true
        continueOnError: false
      posix:
        shell: sh
        run: ./scripts/auth_init.sh
        interactive: true
        continueOnError: false
    postprovision:
      windows:
        shell: pwsh
        run: ./scripts/auth_update.ps1;./scripts/prepdocs.ps1
        interactive: true
        continueOnError: false
      posix:
        shell: sh
        run: ./scripts/auth_update.sh;./scripts/prepdocs.sh
        interactive: true
        continueOnError: false

How can I move forward this point ?
I was following this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/azure-developer-cli/configure-devops-pipeline?tabs=azdo

There is an advanced feature in Azure DevOps that is called "Environment". Just go ahead and create it. It's expected that it would be setup before the pipeline runs as you might want to configure permissions for the environment upfront.

This has nothing to do with Azure Pipelines environments. If the pipeline is running and getting hung up on the azd deploy step, it's because you're missing an earlier step. Based on some quick googling, it looks like azd init is responsible for creating an environment.

According to doc, AZURE_ENV_NAME is the name of the environment created after running azd init or azd env new. I don't see any related scripts in your yaml. Testing your yaml on my side, the deployment is successful when using azd deploy --no-prompt. If it's convenient, can you share your azure.yaml?

Hi @rp346, have you checked my answer below? What's the latest state of the issue? If you want to deploy to the original environment, ensure the value of AZURE_ENV_NAME is the same as the tag's value in your resource groups. If you want to create a new environment, add azd provision --no-prompt before azd deploy --no-prompt.

I can reproduce the issue when I try to change the value of AZURE_ENV_NAME in my pipeline and run azd deploy.
When I run azd init locally, I set the environment to demo. After azd up, I can see tag azd-env-name : demo in the resource group and resources created.

When I change the value of AZURE_ENV_NAME to demo11.

If I use azd deploy, the pipeline will stuck. I can see the same error after canceling the build.


If I use azd deploy --no-prompt, the pipeline will fail with error RROR: getting target resource: getting default resource groups for environment: demo11: resource not found: 0 resource groups with prefix or suffix with value: 'demo11'


If you want to deploy to the original environment, ensure the value of AZURE_ENV_NAME is the same as the tag's value in your resource groups.
If you want to create a new environment, add azd provision --no-prompt before azd deploy --no-prompt.
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: Install azd
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        curl -fsSL https://aka.ms/install-azd.sh | bash

  # azd delegate auth to az to use service connection with AzureCLI@2
  - pwsh: |
      azd config set auth.useAzCliAuth "true"
    displayName: Configure AZD to Use AZ CLI Authentication.

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Provision Infrastructure
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: azconnection
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        azd provision --no-prompt
    env:
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
      AZURE_ENV_NAME: $(AZURE_ENV_NAME)
      AZURE_LOCATION: $(AZURE_LOCATION)

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: Deploy Application
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: azconnection
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        azd deploy --no-prompt
    env:
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
      AZURE_ENV_NAME: $(AZURE_ENV_NAME)
      AZURE_LOCATION: $(AZURE_LOCATION)



Update
Solution:
Include .azure/config.json in the repo which has {"version":1,"defaultEnvironment":"demo"}.
CLI configuration file contains settings that are used for managing CLI behavior. When you provide a default value, that argument is no longer required by any command. Instead, the default value is used.

I have been setting AZURE_ENV_NAME with the correct value present on Resource Group.

Thanks for sharing your solution. CLI configuration file contains settings that are used for managing CLI behavior. When you provide a default value, that argument is no longer required by any command. Instead, the default value is used. To help others who may have the similar issue, I have shared your solution in the answer above to make it clearer.
